# Moving image (object) in a circular direction(path) in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, canvas

I am trying to move image in circular path using onTouchEvent(). I can able to move the image in circular direction but not on exact circular path that i drawn. thanks in advance.

Comment: please guide .... trying from last two days..

Comment: Could you provide more details? What exact problem have you faced? Where's your current code?